# Use rewire with Jest, to spy on console.log used in a private function

Tags: javascript, module, jestjs, private, console.log

I have a private function in one file, which uses `console.log`. I want to check that `console.log` does indeed run, in my [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) test. Therefore to access the private function, I use [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire).

I have the following file:

```
// a.js
function b() {
  console.log('c');
}
```

And I have the following test file, where I use the method [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44344801/how-to-use-jest-with-jsdom-to-test-console-log) to replace `console.log` with a Jest mock function, and the [method here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885024/when-using-rewire-and-sinon-faketimer-order-matters/36025128) to ensure the replacement gets made before the `rewire`:

```
// a.test.js
global.console = {
  log: jest.fn(),
};

const rewire = require('rewire');
const a = rewire('./a');

test('b', () => {
  a.__get__('b')();
  expect(global.console.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Yet when I run the test, I get:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    logger must implement log, warn and error methods
```

And if I use the following test code instead:

```
// a.test.js
const rewire = require('rewire');
const a = rewire('./a');

a.__set__('console', {
  log: jest.fn(),
});

test('b', () => {
  a.__get__('b')();
  expect(global.console.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I get the following error:

```
    expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalled()

jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
Received:
  function: [Function bound log]
```

Is there any way at all to spy on `console.log` when used in a private function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep track of the mock you give `__set__` and assert on it directly:

```
const rewire = require('rewire');
const a = rewire('./a');

const logMock = jest.fn(
  (...args) => console.log('logMock called with', ...args)
);

a.__set__('console', {
  log: logMock,
});

test('b', () => {
  a.__get__('b')();
  expect(logMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Ah yes thanks, that works great! I'm sure this technique will be useful for doing the same thing with other methods, too.